# Prometheus exporter to check file size

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, alerts

I need to check file size and looking for any prometheus exporter which can do that task

My Actual task is -

I wanted to create alert for 0 kb file size and also wanted to make a list of it

I got alerts for 0kb file size in my server using prometheus alerts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/michael-doubez/filestat_exporter (disclaimer: I am the author). You can also get the same result by regularly dumping the file size in a the prom file of a node exporter.